# MySQL: insert where not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert new user if not exist in users table, I tried this query but receive error:

```
INSERT INTO USER (name,email)
VALUES ('John','john@mmm.com')
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT id FROM USER WHERE email = 'john@mmm.com')
```

how to insert user if not exists ?

error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where not exists (select id from user where email = 'john@mmm.com')' at line 5
```

thanks,

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where not exists (select id from user where email = 'john@mmm.com')'

Comment: Why don't you use an IF statement to only perform the INSERT statement on a given condition?...

Comment: @ne1410s how to do this? thanks,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO USER (name, email)
    SELECT 'John', 'john@mmm.com'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT id FROM USER WHERE email = 'john@mmm.com');
```

I would write this as:

```
INSERT INTO USER (name, email)
    SELECT name, email
    FROM (SELECT 'John' as name, 'john@mmm.com' as email) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM USER u WHERE u.email = t.email);
```

But a better approach is probably to just put in a unique index so the database protects the data:

```
create unique index idx_users_email on user(email);
```

Comment: Man I can't understand how you can generate so many high end answers ! This is a proof that your books are top notch but I didn't have time to read one !

Answer (score 10):

Use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) instead of `INSERT`.

```
INSERT INTO USER (name,email)
SELECT 'John','john@mmm.com'
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT id FROM USER WHERE email = 'john@mmm.com')
```

You also might consider using the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax extension of MySQL.

Comment: your query need to have a `FROM` clause otherwise it will throw an error. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82dea

Comment: This is the best solution I have found for mySQL - not all SQL's are allow for the same syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use the **INSERT IGNORE** query.

If the record is a duplicate, then the IGNORE keyword tells MySQL to discard it silently without generating an error.

```
mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO USER (name, email)
   -> VALUES( 'Jay', 'Jay@domain.com');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO USER (name, email)
   -> VALUES( 'Jay', 'Jay@domain.com');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```